# Snowflake - How to use a local variable as a table identifier and detect if data exists in the table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to detect if a table has data.

Here is a test harness to demonstrate the issue. First create a table with some data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE public.SomeTable
(
    id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO public.SomeTable (id) values (1);
```

Now if I run this I receive the results I expect (which is "1"):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(select top 1 1 from identifier('public.SomeTable'))) THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE 
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

However, if I try to use a local variable to store the table name and use that in the identifier I get the strangest error. Here is the erroring SQL:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
  LET tableName string := 'public.SomeTable';
  IF (EXISTS(select top 1 1 from identifier(:tableName))) THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE 
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

...and this is the error I am receiving (goodness knows why it is complaining about 'parse_json'!):

```
syntax error line 1 at position 45 unexpected 'parse_json'. 
syntax error line 1 at position 55 unexpected '('. (line 17)
```

**How can I use a local variable for the table name to test if data exists?**

Comment: I believe you should raise Snowflake ticket to look at this. This error indicates it is not possible to use IDENTIFIER/TABLE with query in IF condition context.

Comment: @nbk Dynamic SQL is not required here(but it could be used). Snowflake has special syntax [IDENTIFIER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal) `SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER(variable_here)`

Comment: that is also disguised dynamic sql and makes it difficult to switch database systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a workaround by introducing helper variable:

```
BEGIN
  LET tableName string := 'public.SomeTable';
  LET helper BOOLEAN := FALSE;

  SELECT TOP 1 TRUE
  INTO :helper
  FROM TABLE(:tableName);
  
  IF (:helper) THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE 
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
```

Output:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| 1 |

Comment: Thank you so much @lukasz-szozda. I really appreciate your answer. I thought I was going mad. I will raise this with Snowflake. Thanks again for the prompt response.

Comment: Update. I raised this with Snowflake and they fixed within 24 hours! The block in the question that previously failed with a PARSE_JSON error now works. Nice work Snowflake! :-)